# Mutate column values to NA whenever column name occurs in different column

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have the following (simplified) data frame:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame("extracolumns" = rep("random", 6),
                 "which.x" = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x2", "x3", "x1"),
                 "which.y" = c("y2", "y2", "y2", "y1", "y1", "y1"),
                 "which.z" = c("z3", "z3", "z3", "z1", "z2", "z1"),
                 "x1" = rnorm(6),
                 "x2" = rnorm(6),
                 "x3" = rnorm(6),
                 "y1" = rnorm(6),
                 "y2" = rnorm(6),
                 "y3" = rnorm(6),
                 "z1" = rnorm(6),
                 "z2" = rnorm(6),
                 "z3" = rnorm(6)) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 2)
```

which gives

```
  extracolumns which.x which.y which.z    x1    x2    x3    y1    y2    y3    z1    z2    z3
1       random      x1      y2      z3 -0.56  0.46  0.40  0.70 -0.63  0.43  0.55 -1.27  0.78
2       random      x2      y2      z3 -0.23 -1.27  0.11 -0.47 -1.69 -0.30 -0.06  2.17 -0.08
3       random      x3      y2      z3  1.56 -0.69 -0.56 -1.07  0.84  0.90 -0.31  1.21  0.25
4       random      x2      y1      z1  0.07 -0.45  1.79 -0.22  0.15  0.88 -0.38 -1.12 -0.03
5       random      x3      y1      z2  0.13  1.22  0.50 -1.03 -1.14  0.82 -0.69 -0.40 -0.04
6       random      x1      y1      z1  1.72  0.36 -1.97 -0.73  1.25  0.69 -0.21 -0.47  1.37
```

I want to mutate values in df such that each row contains NA values for the columns that appear in 'which.x', 'which.y' and 'which.z'. Something like:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  
  df[i, match(df$which.x, colnames(df))[i]] <- NA
  df[i, match(df$which.y, colnames(df))[i]] <- NA
  df[i, match(df$which.z, colnames(df))[i]] <- NA
  
}
```

which gives the desired output:

```
> df
  extracolumns which.x which.y which.z    x1    x2    x3    y1    y2    y3    z1    z2    z3
1       random      x1      y2      z3    NA  0.46  0.40  0.70    NA  0.43  0.55 -1.27    NA
2       random      x2      y2      z3 -0.23    NA  0.11 -0.47    NA -0.30 -0.06  2.17    NA
3       random      x3      y2      z3  1.56 -0.69    NA -1.07    NA  0.90 -0.31  1.21    NA
4       random      x2      y1      z1  0.07    NA  1.79    NA  0.15  0.88    NA -1.12 -0.03
5       random      x3      y1      z2  0.13  1.22    NA    NA -1.14  0.82 -0.69    NA -0.04
6       random      x1      y1      z1    NA  0.36 -1.97    NA  1.25  0.69    NA -0.47  1.37
```

I would like to obtain the same desired result, but more efficiently/elegantly -- perhaps using functions like `across()` and `case_when()` -- but I cannot make it work.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A literal path:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(
    across(x1:x3, ~ if_else(cur_column() == which.x, .[NA], .)), 
    across(y1:y3, ~ if_else(cur_column() == which.y, .[NA], .)), 
    across(z1:z3, ~ if_else(cur_column() == which.z, .[NA], .))
  ) 
#   extracolumns which.x which.y which.z    x1    x2    x3    y1    y2    y3    z1    z2    z3
# 1       random      x1      y2      z3    NA  0.46  0.40  0.70    NA  0.43  0.55 -1.27    NA
# 2       random      x2      y2      z3 -0.23    NA  0.11 -0.47    NA -0.30 -0.06  2.17    NA
# 3       random      x3      y2      z3  1.56 -0.69    NA -1.07    NA  0.90 -0.31  1.21    NA
# 4       random      x2      y1      z1  0.07    NA  1.79    NA  0.15  0.88    NA -1.12 -0.03
# 5       random      x3      y1      z2  0.13  1.22    NA    NA -1.14  0.82 -0.69    NA -0.04
# 6       random      x1      y1      z1    NA  0.36 -1.97    NA  1.25  0.69    NA -0.47  1.37
```

I use `.[NA]` in place of just `NA` to be clear on the type of `NA`: R has at least 8 different types of `NA`, so we need to be explicit about which one; in this case, it'd be `NA_real_`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. There is still one difference from the desired output though; I think the ``false`` argument in the ``if_else()`` function should not be constant as the resulting cell should show the value from the appropriate column (and not, for instance, all equal those from x1). Any idea on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Oops, typo retained from dev. It's been fixed, see my edits.

Answer (score 3):

Using `pivot_longer` then `pivot_wider`:

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("which")) %>% 
  mutate(across(x1:z3, ~ replace(.x, cur_column() == value, NA)),
         id = cumsum(name == "which.x")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id, unused_fn = min)
```

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 14
     id which.x which.y which.z extracolumns    x1    x2    x3    y1    y2    y3    z1    z2    z3
  <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 x1      y2      z3      random       NA    -1.43  1.92 -0.92 NA    -0.59  1.42  0.81 NA   
2     2 x2      y2      z3      random       -0.38 NA     0.56 -0.07 NA     1.29 -0.72 -0.67 NA   
3     3 x3      y2      z3      random       -1.34 -2.02 NA    -0.23 NA     0.74  0.24 -0.55 NA   
4     4 x2      y1      z1      random        0.72 NA     1.59 NA    -0.09  0.32 NA    -0.88  0.1 
5     5 x3      y1      z2      random       -1.38 -1.83 NA    NA    -0.07  1.1   0.08 NA     0.67
6     6 x1      y1      z1      random       NA     0.61  1.15 NA     1.1  -0.84 NA     0.28 -0.45
```

---

Or, with `rowwise`:

```r
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(across(x1:z3, ~ replace(.x, any(across(starts_with("which")) == cur_column()), NA)))
```

---

Or with `if_any`:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(across(x1:z3, \(x){
    cur <- cur_column()
    replace(x, if_any(starts_with("which"), \(y) y == cur), NA)
    }
    ))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do it in one call to  `across()` and use `if_any()` inside `ifelse()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
  
df %>% 
  mutate(across(x1:z3,
                \(x) {
                  this_col <- cur_column()
                  ifelse(
                    if_any(starts_with("which"), ~ .x == this_col),
                    NA,
                    x)
                  }))

#>   extracolumns which.x which.y which.z    x1    x2    x3    y1    y2    y3
#> 1       random      x1      y2      z3    NA  0.46  0.40  0.70    NA  0.43
#> 2       random      x2      y2      z3 -0.23    NA  0.11 -0.47    NA -0.30
#> 3       random      x3      y2      z3  1.56 -0.69    NA -1.07    NA  0.90
#> 4       random      x2      y1      z1  0.07    NA  1.79    NA  0.15  0.88
#> 5       random      x3      y1      z2  0.13  1.22    NA    NA -1.14  0.82
#> 6       random      x1      y1      z1    NA  0.36 -1.97    NA  1.25  0.69
#>      z1    z2    z3
#> 1  0.55 -1.27    NA
#> 2 -0.06  2.17    NA
#> 3 -0.31  1.21    NA
#> 4    NA -1.12 -0.03
#> 5 -0.69    NA -0.04
#> 6    NA -0.47  1.37
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>